# How do I apply a function to a tuple?

Tags: python, function, tuples

This should be an easy one: how do I apply a function to a tuple in Python?

Viz.:

```
Python 3.9.9 (main, Nov 16 2021, 09:34:38) 
[Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def g(a,b):
...   return a+b
... 
>>> tup = (3,4)
>>> 
>>> g(tup)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: g() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
>>> g.apply(tup)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'apply'
>>> apply(g,tup)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'apply' is not defined
```

I can certainly write a version of `g` that expects a tuple, or even a conversion function that does it for a general 2-arg function:

```
>>> def conv2(fun):
...   def tuplefun(tup):
...     (a,b) = tup
...     return fun(a,b)
...   return tuplefun
... 
>>> tuple_g = conv2(g)
>>> tuple_g(tup)
7
```

... but this doesn't work for the general case of an arbitrary-arity function.

(ObResearch: I searched for an answer to this question for about five minutes and found a whole bunch of questions about pandas dataframes but none that appeared to answer this question. I'm sure this has an easy answer, and I apologize for not finding it, but if I'm not finding it, then probably lots of others are too... in other words, a "duplicate of question #XXXXX" would be very welcome here.)

(As an ironic-to-me side note, my most-liked question is *exactly this same question* about the Scala language, from back in 2010. I guess my role in life is functional-programmer-raiding-other-languages...?)

Comment: "I searched for an answer to this question for about five minutes" Did you try putting `python variable arguments` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+variable+arguments)? Or [`python arguments from tuple`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+arguments+from+tuple)? Or [`python unpack tuple into arguments`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+unpack+tuple+into+arguments) (a suggestion I get from the previous one)? When I try any of these, I immediately get relevant answers off the top. What did you search for instead?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I searched for "apply function to tuple". I just did it again, and again found nothing useful. I strongly suspect that the issue here is my use of the word "apply". Sorry to be such a PL person!

Comment: Yeah... when you say "apply" to people using non-FP languages, they generally think you mean the thing that you would call `map`; and explaining the difference between `apply` and `fold` might be tricky as well. (Incidentally, Python does have `map` as a builtin, and also comprehensions; and the standard library provides a fold, but calls it `reduce`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use tuple unpacking syntax:

```
>>> def g(a,b):
...   return a+b
... 
>>> tup = (3,4)
>>> 
>>> g(*tup)
```

Answer (score 2):

You write it like this:

```
>>> g(*tup)
```